# Abstract Algebra, group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Can someone please help me with this question.

Prove that the set of permutations of a set S is a closed under the operation of composition.

I know that for something to be closed that means two elements in the set under some operation will stay in the set.

Comment: It means simply that if the composition of two permutations of $S$ is again a permutation of $S$, which is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

A permutation of a set $X$ is a bijection $f:X\rightarrow X$. Therefore, any composition of permutations must stay in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Although this problem is very simple, the key is to use the fact that the composition of bijections is also a bijection.

A permutation of $S$ is a bijection from $S$ to $S$.

Let $a$, $b$ be permutations of $S$.

Since the composition of two bijections is also a bijection, $ab$ is a bijection from $S$ to $S$.

Hence $ab$ is also a permutation of $S$, and the set of permutations of $S$ is closed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please, format your posts using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

A permutation of a set $X$ is nothing mire than a bijective function $f:X \to X$. If $g,h:X \to X)$ are permutations (hence elements of $\mathbb{S}$) then $g \circ h: X \to X$ and $h \circ g: X \to X$ are both bijective function. Therefore $g \circ h, h \circ g \in \mathbb{S}$ and hence $\mathbb{S}$ is closed under the composition of functions.